# Can't get FadeIn to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my background to fadeIn on button click, am I doing it correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#d_clip_container').click(function() {
            $('#d_clip_button').css('background-image','url(img/steps.png)').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What browser? Some older ones such as IE8 can't fade transparent PNGs.

Comment: Can you show html stucture, or give not working live example?

Comment: You'll probably need to have the background on a separate element and animate that element's opacity.

Answer (score 1):

is `$("#d_clip_button")` visible before you call `.fadeIn()` ?

if it's visible, `.fadeIn()` would do nothing..

Comment: Ah, yes it is. I want to fade the background on the button.

Comment: then, you need to hide the background before you fade it in

Comment: i think that isn really possible

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#d_clip_button').css({'background-image':'url(img/steps.png)','display':'none'});
        $('#d_clip_container').click(function() {
            $('#d_clip_button').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fadein background, you can fadein only HTML elements like the whole button.

I think `.animate()` can do the trick.